# Django Error: 'cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object' when Using Cache with Context Data

Tags: python, django, caching

I'm encountering a challenging issue in my Django project related to caching and context data. When trying to cache the context data in a view, I'm receiving the error message: "cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object."

The error seems to occur in my view that displays detailed information about a book, and I'm attempting to cache certain parts of the context, such as average ratings, recommended books, and the last books.

There is my detail book view and model:

```
#views.py

class DetailBookView(DetailView):
    template_name = "books/book-detail.html"
    queryset = Book.objects.all().select_related("genre")
    cache_timeout = 60

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        cache_key = f"book_detail_{obj.id}"

        cached_data = cache.get(cache_key)

        if cached_data is not None:
            context.update(cached_data)

            # average rating book
            context["avg"] = BookRelations.objects.get_rating(book=obj)
            # generate 3 random book
            context["recommended"] = Book.objects.get_recommended(obj.genre)
            # last 3 books
            context["last_books"] = self.get_queryset().values("title")
        else:
            cache.set(cache_key, context, self.cache_timeout)

        return context



#models.py (Books)
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_recommended(self, genre):
        recommend_books = list(Book.objects.filter(genre=genre).select_related("owner"))
        if len(recommend_books) < 3:
            recommend_books += list(self.get_queryset())[:4]
        return random.sample(recommend_books, 3)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(5)], max_digits=3, decimal_places=2
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="book_img/",
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(["jpg", "JPEG"])],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="my_books")

    objects = BookManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm still not entirely sure about the root cause, but I suspect that the issue might be related to a specific part of my code. That's why I'm including the following section of my code for your reference:

```
#models.py (book-relations)
class BookRelationsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset.annotate()
        return queryset.filter(models.Q(bookmark=True) | models.Q(rating__gt=0))

    def get_rating(self, book):
        rating = (
            self.get_queryset()
            .filter(book=book)
            .aggregate(avg_rating=models.Avg("rating"))["avg_rating"]
        )
        return rating if rating else 0


class BookRelations(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOISES = (
        (1, 1),
        (2, 2),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 4),
        (5, 5),
    )

    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="book_relation"
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_rait")

    bookmark = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rating = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOISES, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = BookRelationsManager()
```

I've taken several steps to address the issue, including ensuring that the variables in the template ({{object}}, {{object.owner}}, {{avg}}, {{recommended}}, and {{last_books}}) contain only serializable data. I've also reviewed the AJAX requests and cache usage.

I've already verified the serialization of my model using a serializer, and it's functioning correctly. Despite this, I'm encountering difficulties when trying to cache certain context data in my Django project. This has raised questions about which specific data elements could be causing the serialization issue when working with the cache.

Your insights and suggestions on what types of data might be problematic for serialization when using the Django cache would be incredibly helpful in troubleshooting this issue. Thank you for your assistance.

However, the problem persists, and I'm unable to pinpoint the exact source of the issue. I'm looking for guidance on identifying and resolving this error. Any suggestions or insights into what could be causing the "cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object" error would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance.